# Concatenate all the columns row by row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to concatenate all the columns row by row. This code is working but it keeps looping until excel shuts down. How do I make sure that this only loops a number of times equal to the total number of rows being used?

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```html
Sub Combine_row_by_row()

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim x As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim ColMax As Integer
Dim i As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
ColMax = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    row = 1
Do While Cells(row, "A").value < LastRow
    With Worksheets("Formula2")
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(row, 1), .Cells(row, ColMax))
    End With

    x = ""

    For Each cel In rng

        x = x & cel.value

    Next

    Sheets("Formula2").Cells(row, 1).value = x

row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells(row, "A").Value returns the contents in the cell. Unless that column contains a list of the row numbers, these values may never exceeed the value of the LastRow variable. You probably want Cells(row, "A").Row

Comment: Thank you, that was the perfect fix!